# Guzzle Laravel simple connection and errors checker

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle, laravel-livewire

Im using Guzzle on a laravel Project,
I want to have a working validation for Api connection and error checker,
Also want to keep a sequence while checking, for example, first check the connection if its 200 if isnt then show the Connection error message.
If is 200 then proceed to second check that checking if has errors from the remote server like "duplicate ID" then show the error message.
If has no error then make the POST or GET request
is it possible that?
because now when i run this im getting error regarding variable $errormsg
error:

```
 Trying to get property 'error' of non-object
```

And thats happened because if hasn't errors on server response the field strval(simplexml_load_string($response)->response->errors->error->message)  doesnt exist on xml , so is it possible to check if that field is empty or not without getting error?

My function:

````
  public function showinvoice()
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'http_errors' => false,
            'headers' => [
                'aade-user-id' => 'blabla',
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'blablabla',
               
            ]
        ]);

        $request = $client->GET('https://mydatapi.aade.gr/myDATA/RequestMyExpenses/?dateFrom=11/11/2021&dateTo=11/12/2022');

        $response = $request->getBody()->getContents();

        $reasonPhrase = $request->getReasonPhrase();

        $statusCode = $request->getStatusCode();
        $errormsg = strval(simplexml_load_string($response)->response->errors->error->message);
        if ($statusCode <= 200) { 

            if (isset($errormsg)) {

                $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', ['type' => 'error', 'message' => $errormsg]);
            }
            else{
               return $response;
            }
   
        } 
        else {
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', ['type' => 'error', 'message' => $statusCode .' '. $reasonPhrase]);
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Please write your question a lot more clearly using proper sentences, punctuation and grammar, and some layout. Right now it is very hard to understand what you are saying. If writing in English is difficult for you please find someone to help you translate. See also [ask] for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Also if you are getting an error please tell us what it says (although I wasn't totally clear if that's what is happening or not - see my first comment).

Comment: @ADyson Sry but  I didn't come here to do an English competition , also i don't think everyone here writes english fluently, especially if it's not the mother language... 
In my project now, i make some corrections, i think is understandable , simply want with some way  to check the  $errormsg without getting error (the error is on post)

Comment: No but stackoverflow is not a freelance sites to get your problems solved without expecting some sort of quality. The first paragraph is pretty hard to understand, it is not about correct spelling, it is about explaining the problem properly. Questions moving forward should be a good index for other developers than you, to get help, understand and fix similar problems. If we do not uphold that standard, we loose that indexing factor that has made stackoverflow what it is today.

Comment: True it's not a competition. But if you write unclearly then people spend more time trying to figure out what you're saying than actually helping you, which is the thing you wanted. My comment was for your benefit, not mine. Make it as easy as possible for people to assist you. Presentation  is inportant as well - for example if you're laying out a series of conditions then a bullet list is an excellent way to show them in an easily-digestible way. If it's all just prose then decoding it becomes like untangling mental spaghetti

Comment: Anyway, `is it possible to check if that field is empty `...yes, use the `empty` or `isset` function